# Rectangular prism in power point

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Is there a way to make a rectangular prism using the insert shapes feature of powerpoint?  I can make a prism out of the cube, but that only gives me control of 2 out of the 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative way of achieving this which has some advantages and some disadvantages depending on what you are using it for. The steps are as follows:

- Create a rectangle to represent one side of the prism (via **Shapes -> Rectangle**).
- Right-click the rectangle and choose **Format Shape...**.
- Choose **3-D Format** tab.
- Choose a depth. You can specify a variety of units including pt (points), px (pixels) and cm (centimetres).
- Click the **3-D Rotation** tab.
- Choose a rotation from the presets.

Advantages:

- More realistic 3D (including perspective and lighting).
- More precise control over the size of each dimension.

Disadvantages:

- Cannot connect other shapes to the sides like you can with the other method.

Example:

[image: Example of 3D prisms]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can control all the dimensions of a cube.

Below is a screen-capture from Office 2007. There are handles to handle every dimension.
Maybe the one you are missing is the yellow handle :

[image]